# Задача в JAVA, домашнее задание

Tags: java

Есть задача :
Написать примитивную программу в JAVA для заполнения массива чисел из 10 элементов значениями переменной а, при условии что а является членом арифметической прогрессии 2а-1, а1=4.
Правильно ли я понимаю что все елементы будут заполнены цифрой 7?

```
public void fillArrNum (int [] arr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 2*arr[i-1];
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: нет, неправильно. У вас будет 10 элементов, которые зависят от введенной переменной a. но вообще, вопрос не особо связан с программированием, поэтому рискует быть закрытым. Конкретизируйте вопрос, чтобы он касался программирования.

Comment: @Denis я не знаю как решить задачу, задача должна быть реализована на Java, что конкретизировать?

Comment: К сожалению, тут не принято делать домашнее задание за других. Вы можете показать свои наработки и вам с ними помогут. У вас есть программа, которую вы сами постарались написать? Если да - добавьте, пожалуйста, её код в ваш вопрос.

Comment: @Denis Я хочу написать цикл принимающий массив, в цикле заполнять элементы массива переменной а, мне не понятно как на переменную влияет пример арифметической прогрессии.Не могу понять в чем подвох.

Comment: Я думаю, суть задачи заключается в том, что в формуле 2а-1 'a' - это предыдущий элемент. а второе =2а первое - 1 а третье =2а второе - 1

Comment: Вопрос остался открытым( Это правильно?     public void fillArrNum (int [] arr)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = 2*arr[i-1];
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

Comment: @Denis добавил код

Comment: `Правильно ли я понимаю что все елементы будут заполнены цифрой 7?` - смотря что у вас в `arr`, который передается в функцию)

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю что при `i = 0`  `arr[i-1]` поломается)

Comment: Не правильно. У вас вылетит ошибка, когда вы попытаетесь обратиться к элементу массива с отрицательным индексом arr[-1]. Попробуйте такое условие цикла for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)

Answer (score 4):

@Петр, если я правильно понимаю, то основная задача данного задания - это заполнение массива из 10 элементов. При этом первый элемент `a = 4`, каждый последующий `а = 2а-1`. Я предполагаю, что код должен выглядеть так:

```
int[] generateArray() {
    int[] resultArray = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0, a = 4; i < resultArray.length; a = 2a - 1, i++) {
        resultArray[i] = a;
    }
    return resultArray;
}
```